# Why does arrays handle strings containing swedish ÅÄÖ characters by using two or more indexes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsxmlparser

Ok, my problem is that whenever i collect data from the parser into an array where the string contains Swedish ÅÄÖ characters. In my example the

```
[schemaInfoArray objectAtIndex:3]
```

is supposed to be @"Lördag" but is saved as @"L" and the

```
[schemaInfoArray objectAtIndex:4]
```

contains the rest of the string that gets presented as 
@"ördag"

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

    {

        tempStrang = string;
        [schemaInfoArray insertObject:tempStrang atIndex:uppraknare];
        uppraknare++;



    }



    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
        {




            if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"schemaInfo"] ) 
            {

            }
            if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"modfromtid"] ) 
            {
                frommodarbtid = [schemaInfoArray objectAtIndex:0];
            }

            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"modtomtid"] ) 
            {
                tommodarbtid = [schemaInfoArray objectAtIndex:1];
            }
            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"modrast"] ) 
            {
                modrast = [schemaInfoArray objectAtIndex:2];
            }
            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"benamning"] ) 
            {
                benamning = [schemaInfoArray objectAtIndex:3];

            }
            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"fromnormarb"] ) 
            {
                fromnormarbtid = [schemaInfoArray objectAtIndex:4];
            }
            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"tomnormarb"] ) 
            {
                tomnormarbtid = [schemaInfoArray objectAtIndex:5];
            }
            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"rast"] ) 
            {
                normrast = [schemaInfoArray objectAtIndex:6];
            }       

        }
```

Does anyone have any thoughts about how to actually get @"Lördag" to be saved into ONE index instead of getting split into several indexes? This really destroys the structure of things that is supposed to be presented.

Comment: I don't know the slightest about Objective C, but it would seem that the problem is caused by the compiler using an 8-bit ASCII extension rather than Unicode.

Comment: Can you post parts of the XML? Kind of hard to see what you are doing here without any real sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [documented design choice from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate), and has nothing to do with Swedish characters:

> Because *string* may be only part of
>   the total character content for the
>   current element, you should append it
>   to the current accumulation of
>   characters until the element changes.

So you should do just as they say: use a `NSMutableString` to accumulate the results, and when the element changes, save the buffer to a permanent, (preferrably) immutable `NSString`.

As requested, here's an example. It was written without any kind of IDE, so chances are that it'll work, but there's no guarantee that it will either compile or work.

```
@interface Foo : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    NSMutableString* accumulator;
    NSMutableArray* schemaInfoArray;
    int uppraknare; // whatever 'uppraknare' means
}

/* snip */

@end

@implementation Foo

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser foundCharacters:(NSString*)string
{
    // only accumulate characters, until we get notified that we went through
    // the whole XML element
    [accumulator appendString:string];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser didEndElement:(NSString*)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString*)nsuri qualifiedName:(NSString*)qName
{
    // we went through the whole element! time to save!
    NSString* immutableResult = [accumulator copy];
    [schemaInfoArray insertObject:immutableResult atIndex:uppraknare];
    uppraknare++;
    [immutableResult release];
    // clear the accumulator for the next element
    [accumulator deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [accumulator length])];

    /* the rest of your code here */
}

@end
```

Comment: Yes, and the total character content is Lördag. Not L nor ördag. 

Could you please, write a code example pointing me in the right direction to solve this problem?

Comment: @user679954 I've put an example.

Answer (score 1):

`-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string` is not guaranteed to contain the complete contents of the string. You need to have a class instance variable that is a NSMutableString that can append all of foundCharacters between the calls to didStartElement and didEndElement. Inside of didEndElement add the the string to the `schemaInfoArray`.